# Indefinite Integral long time plotting

Tags: plotting

I have this equation:

```
PwD = (1/200)*
  Integrate[(1/(E^(0.25/\[Tau])*\[Tau]))*
    Integrate[(1 + 
        2*Sum[(Cos[0.8*n*Pi]*Cos[(n*Pi)/2 - (n*Pi*z)/100])/
           E^((n^2*Pi^2*\[Tau])/10000), {n, 1, 100}])/
      E^((Tan[\[Psi]*Degree]^2*(z + 30)^2)/(4*\[Tau])), {z, -50, 
      50}], {\[Tau], 0, t}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
Now, to generate graphics for different angles `\[Psi]` this is what I did:

```
Pw1 = (Exp[-0.25/t]/t)*
   Integrate[
    Exp[-(((Tan[0 Degree]^2)*(z + 30)^2)/(4*t))]*(1 + 
       2*Sum[Exp[-((n^2)*(Pi^2)*t)/(100^2)]*Cos[0.8*n*Pi]*
          Cos[(n*Pi/2) - (n*Pi*z/100)], {n, 1, 100}]), {z, -50, 50}];
Pw2 = (Exp[-0.25/t]/t)*
   Integrate[
    Exp[-(((Tan[30 Degree]^2)*(z + 30)^2)/(4*t))]*(1 + 
       2*Sum[Exp[-((n^2)*(Pi^2)*t)/(100^2)]*Cos[0.8*n*Pi]*
          Cos[(n*Pi/2) - (n*Pi*z/100)], {n, 1, 100}]), {z, -50, 50}];
Pw3 = (Exp[-0.25/t]/t)*
   Integrate[
    Exp[-(((Tan[60 Degree]^2)*(z + 30)^2)/(4*t))]*(1 + 
       2*Sum[Exp[-((n^2)*(Pi^2)*t)/(100^2)]*Cos[0.8*n*Pi]*
          Cos[(n*Pi/2) - (n*Pi*z/100)], {n, 1, 100}]), {z, -50, 50}];

PD1[y_] := 0.005*NIntegrate[Pw1, {t, 0, y}, MaxRecursion -> 20];
PD2[y_] := 0.005*NIntegrate[Pw2, {t, 0, y}, MaxRecursion -> 20];
PD3[y_] := 0.005*NIntegrate[Pw3, {t, 0, y}, MaxRecursion -> 20];

T1 = Table[{y, 
    PD1[y]}, {y, {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 2, 
     2.2, 2.5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
     18, 19, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 
     90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 
     500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000, 1100, 
     1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000, 2100, 2200,
      2300, 2400, 2500, 2600, 2700, 2800, 2900, 3000, 3500, 4000, 
     4500, 5000, 5500, 6000, 6500, 7000, 7500, 8000, 8500, 9000, 9500,
      10000, 11000, 13000, 15000, 17000, 19000, 20000, 22000, 24000, 
     26000, 28000, 30000, 35000, 40000, 45000, 50000, 55000, 60000, 
     65000, 70000, 75000, 80000, 90000, 95000, 100000, 150000, 200000,
      250000, 300000, 350000, 400000, 450000, 500000, 550000, 600000, 
     700000, 800000, 900000, 1000000}}];
T2 = Table[{y, 
    PD2[y]}, {y, {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 2, 
     2.2, 2.5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
     18, 19, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 
     90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 
     500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000, 1100, 
     1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000, 2100, 2200,
      2300, 2400, 2500, 2600, 2700, 2800, 2900, 3000, 3500, 4000, 
     4500, 5000, 5500, 6000, 6500, 7000, 7500, 8000, 8500, 9000, 9500,
      10000, 11000, 13000, 15000, 17000, 19000, 20000, 22000, 24000, 
     26000, 28000, 30000, 35000, 40000, 45000, 50000, 55000, 60000, 
     65000, 70000, 75000, 80000, 90000, 95000, 100000, 150000, 200000,
      250000, 300000, 350000, 400000, 450000, 500000, 550000, 600000, 
     700000, 800000, 900000, 1000000}}];
T3 = Table[{y, 
    PD3[y]}, {y, {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 2, 
     2.2, 2.5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
     18, 19, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 
     90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 
     500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000, 1100, 
     1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000, 2100, 2200,
      2300, 2400, 2500, 2600, 2700, 2800, 2900, 3000, 3500, 4000, 
     4500, 5000, 5500, 6000, 6500, 7000, 7500, 8000, 8500, 9000, 9500,
      10000, 11000, 13000, 15000, 17000, 19000, 20000, 22000, 24000, 
     26000, 28000, 30000, 35000, 40000, 45000, 50000, 55000, 60000, 
     65000, 70000, 75000, 80000, 90000, 95000, 100000, 150000, 200000,
      250000, 300000, 350000, 400000, 450000, 500000, 550000, 600000, 
     700000, 800000, 900000, 1000000}}];

PwD1 = Interpolation[T1];
PwD2 = Interpolation[T2];
PwD3 = Interpolation[T3];

P1 = LogLogPlot[{PwD1[y], y*PwD1'[y]}, {y, 0.1, 1000000}, 
   PlotRange -> {0.01, 10}, PlotStyle -> {{Black}, {Dashed, Black}}, 
   Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {tD, "PD e tD*PD'"}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}];
P2 = LogLogPlot[{PwD2[y], y*PwD2'[y]}, {y, 0.1, 1000000}, 
   PlotRange -> {0.01, 10}, PlotStyle -> {{Brown}, {Dashed, Brown}}];
P3 = LogLogPlot[{PwD3[y], y*PwD3'[y]}, {y, 0.1, 1000000}, 
   PlotRange -> {0.01, 10}, PlotStyle -> {{Purple}, {Dashed, Purple}}];

Show[P1, P2, P3]
```

The problem is that it takes a very long time to compute these codes, due to the summation limit (1 to 100)! ... Could anyone propose an alternative way to computing this plot?

Comment: Is there any way you can simplify the problem? Is there, by chance, an analytical integral you could pre-compute?

Comment: When posting blocks of code, please prefix it with four spaces. The easiest way is to select the block of code and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-k. Only use backward quotes for inline code.

Comment: Verbeia, unfortunately I believe it doesn’t. I already have made simplification to express like this...

Comment: Check out [Rolf Mertig's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5952/52) on your other post. In summary, he maps `Integrate` across each term in the sum which can then be done in parallel. Additionally, he calculates them as indefinite integrals, substituting the end-points after the integrals have been performed. All together, he sees a dramatic speed up.

Comment: Please post a short and more to the point question. As far as I can tell, everything above the second code block isn't relevant. Second, you want to speed up `PD1`. It's much easier to work out what's going on for us if you ask that, instead of posting your notebook and expecting us to work out where the bottleneck is. I did it because I was stuck waiting for someone, but it took me 30min to reorganize your code, 5min to speed it up (although not enough I'm afraid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible approach. The basic idea is to `Integrate` a single term of the sum over *z*, and do the sum afterwards. I use the undefined symbol `tps` to represent `Tan[psi]` as this seems to speed the integration up.

For the numerical integration, I apply `Re` to the function since we know the answer is real and there's no point having `NIntegrate` spend time worrying over tiny imaginary parts which shouldn't even be there. I've also split the integrations into individual sections rather than starting at 0 every time.

```
\[Psi]=60Degree;
(* the z integral is faster if we keep Tan[psi] undefined,
but we need to deal with the Tan[psi]=0 case separately*)
tanpart=If[Tan[\[Psi]]==0,1,Exp[-(tps^2(z+30)^2)/(4\[Tau])]];
(* this is the term in the sum *)
term=Cos[4n Pi/5]Cos[n Pi/2-n Pi z/100]Exp[-n^2 Pi^2 \[Tau]/10000]tanpart;
(* integrate over z *)
zint=Integrate[term,{z,-50,50}];
(* this is the n=0 term *)
zint0=Integrate[tanpart,{z,-50,50}];
(* now do the sum and insert the value of Tan[psi] *)
summed=(0.005/\[Tau])Exp[-1/(4\[Tau])]*(zint0+2Sum[zint,{n,1,100}])/.tps->Tan[\[Psi]];
(* y values *)
yvals={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,2,2.2,2.5,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500,550,600,650,700,750,800,850,900,950,1000,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500,1600,1700,1800,1900,2000,2100,2200,2300,2400,2500,2600,2700,2800,2900,3000,3500,4000,4500,5000,5500,6000,6500,7000,7500,8000,8500,9000,9500,10000,11000,13000,15000,17000,19000,20000,22000,24000,26000,28000,30000,35000,40000,45000,50000,55000,60000,65000,70000,75000,80000,90000,95000,100000,150000,200000,250000,300000,350000,400000,450000,500000,550000,600000,700000,800000,900000,1000000};
(* integration limits *)
intervals=Most@Transpose@{yvals,RotateLeft[yvals]};
(* do the numerical integrations *)
sections=NIntegrate[Re@summed,{\[Tau],#[[1]],#[[2]]},PrecisionGoal->5]&/@intervals;
(* final results *)
values=Accumulate[sections];
```

Comment: Hey Simon, thanks! Last week I was trying to do exactly that... But I wasn't able to find the proper codes for it. This really helps. Also, I'm trying to run mathematica in Linux, it seem to speed up a lot... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried defining your functions like this:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[t_, z_] = 
  Total@Table[
    Exp[-((n^2)*(Pi^2)*t)/(100^2)]*Cos[0.8*n*Pi]*
     Cos[(n*Pi/2) - (n*Pi*z/100)], {n, 1, 100}];

Pw1[t_?NumericQ] := (Exp[-0.25/t]/t)*
   NIntegrate[
    Exp[-(((Tan[0 Degree]^2)*(z + 30)^2)/(4*t))]*(1 + 
       2*f[t, z]), {z, -50, 50}];

Pw2[t_?NumericQ] := (Exp[-0.25/t]/t)*
   NIntegrate[
    Exp[-(((Tan[30 Degree]^2)*(z + 30)^2)/(4*t))]*(1 + 
       2*f[t, z]), {z, -50, 50}];

Pw3[t_] := (Exp[-0.25/t]/t)*
   NIntegrate[
    Exp[-(((Tan[60 Degree]^2)*(z + 30)^2)/(4*t))]*(1 + 
       2*f[t, z]), {z, -50, 50}];
```

then if `PD1[y_] := 
 0.005*NIntegrate[Pw1[t], {t, 0, y}, MaxRecursion -> 20, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 5]`, `PD[0.1]` takes 40s on my machine.

That's all I have time for right now I'm afraid.